# Haml to HTML/erb...can anyone see the mistake I'm making

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

I forked a Rails project that uses Haml, which I haven't really learned. There's an online converter that helped me with the HTML, but it ignores the erb, and when I tested my own conversion, the flash messages didn't have the classes associated with them, so I know I did it wrong, but I can't see why.

Note (don't worry about spacing in the haml. in the code i have

Original haml

```
 - if flash[:notice]
        .alert-message.warning
          %p
            = flash[:notice]
      - if flash[:error]
        .alert-message.error
          %p
            = flash[:error]
```

faulty Html translation

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
    <div class="alert-message.warning">
    <p>
     <%= flash[:notice] %>
    </p>
    </div>
 <% end %>
   <% if flash[:error] %>
   <div class="alert-message.error">
   <p>
   <%= flash[:error] %>
   </p>
   </div>
   <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a huge indentation after first line. It should be 2 spaces.

**edited**: In case you need to convert small part of haml you can learn how to convert it manually. There is the little [haml tutorial](http://haml-lang.com/tutorial.html) where you can learn some basics.
That part of haml can be turned into following erb:

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
  <div class="alert-message warning">
   <p><%= flash[:notice] %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
<% if flash[:error] %>
  <div class="alert-message error">
   <p><%= flash[:error] %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

where:
`-` same as `<%`

`=` same as `<%=`

`%p` (`%tag_name`) -> `<p>`

`.class` -> `%div.class` -> `<div class="class"`

**edited#2**: 
judging by generated html `<div class="alert-message.warning">` should be `<div class="alert-message warning">` (dot replaced by space between classes)

Comment: sorry, half the question was invisible. I'm translating FROM haml to the html/erb..the html/erb is not working

Comment: so I had it right. mine's the same as yours, but it's not working on my site..hmm.

Comment: the problem was that I put the "." instead of spaces. Didn't see that. thanks